# How to transfer SPL-tokens using Rust

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, rust, nft

I want to add to my smart-contract tranfer SPL-tokens. How i can do that?
If I have ATA, receiverATA, mint, amount, decimals.

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    program::invoke,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    system_instruction,
};

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {

    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
```

How do I properly pass all data through JavaScript if I use `TransactionInstruction` how do I properly pass `amount` and `decimals` to `data:`

Answer (score 0):

There's an example program that transfers SPL tokens in a program at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/examples/rust/transfer-tokens, so pulling from that, you'll need to do something like:

```
/// Instruction processor
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Create an iterator to safely reference accounts in the slice
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    // Assume that the amount is passed in as 8 bytes of instruction data
    let amount = u64::from_le_bytes(instruction_data[..8].try_into().unwrap());

    // As part of the program specification the instruction gives:
    let source_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 1.
    let mint_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 2.
    let destination_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 3.
    let authority_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 4.
    let token_program_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 5.

    // The program uses `transfer_checked`, which requires the number of decimals
    // in the mint, so extract that from the account data too.
    let mint = Mint::unpack(&mint_info.try_borrow_data()?)?;
    let decimals = mint.decimals;

    // Invoke the transfer
    msg!("Attempting to transfer {} tokens", amount);
    invoke(
        &transfer_checked(
            token_program_info.key,
            source_info.key,
            mint_info.key,
            destination_info.key,
            authority_info.key,
            &[], // no multisig allowed
            amount,
            decimals,
        )
        .unwrap(),
        &[
            source_info.clone(),
            mint_info.clone(),
            destination_info.clone(),
            authority_info.clone(),
            token_program_info.clone(), // not required, but better for clarity
        ],
    )
}
```

So we pass in all of the accounts required for the transfer along with an amount, encoded as a little-endian u64. To create the transaction then, you can do:

```
// Create an instruction following the account order expected by the program
    let transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
        &[Instruction::new_with_bytes(
            program_id,
            &amount.to_le_bytes(),
            vec![
                AccountMeta::new(source.pubkey(), false),
                AccountMeta::new_readonly(mint.pubkey(), false),
                AccountMeta::new(destination.pubkey(), false),
                AccountMeta::new_readonly(authority_pubkey, false),
                AccountMeta::new_readonly(spl_token::id(), false),
            ],
        )],
        Some(&payer.pubkey()),
        &[&payer],
        recent_blockhash,
    );
```